# Writing a dynamic field to Kusto in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-explorer

We've used https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark to connect Kusto to our Spark app.
We have a field that is written to Kusto as a Scala object (dynamic in Kusto).
The empty String ("") fields in that object are written to Kusto as an undefined/null value, i.e. (note field "d", which should be ""):

```
{
   "x": "y",
   "obj": {
       "a": 64,
       "b": [],
       "c": "Linux",
       "d": ,
       ...
   },
   "a": "b"
}
```

[JSON example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTjvl.png)

This breaks the validity of the underlying JSON format, meaning the query cannot access any fields in this object (XXX['obj'] returns null for any field). Is there a way to ensure empty strings are written to Kusto as ""?

Thanks

Comment: what version did you use?

Comment: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource 1.0.2

Comment: we are working on a fix for this issue , thank you for reaching out to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed on version 1.1.2 of the connector